# Pygame Game with Notes

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to learn pygame and I was wondering if anyone knew of a game that included notes within the script which explains what each line of code does. Preferably a very simple game that just outlines the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [PyPong](https://github.com/furbiesandbeans/PyPong) or [Doodle-Jump](https://github.com/thefrolov/Doodle-Jump)

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the [pygame.org](http://pygame.org/)?

There are lots of projects in the right menu, you just select the category and download the source